# Simulating Outcomes from a Random Effects Model - Strange Behavior when Changing Number of Effects

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, simulation

I've have been doing my best to generate observations from a random effects model so that I can compare estimates of parameters to true parameters for a variety of conditions (like number of random effects, different magnitudes of standard deviation among the effects, etc).

I have been following the guidance from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483509/simulating-observations-for-a-2-way-anova-in-r-w-mixed-effects-model-and-reco) (my last post) where I got some good advice on how to go about simulating from these types of models.  In summary, the advice was to set up a dummy experiment, extract the design matrix Z from that setup, draw your random effects and assemble into a vector, then use the design matrix Z and the random effect to construct the simulated observations.  Then fit a model to the observations to see the estimate:

```
set.seed(15)
n.part <- 20  # number of parts
n.oper <- 20  # number of opers
n.reps <- 2   # number of replications

dt <- expand.grid(part = LETTERS[1:n.part], oper = 1:n.oper, reps = 1:n.reps)

dt$Y <- 10 + rnorm(n.part*n.oper*n.reps)

myformula <- "Y ~ (1|part) + (1|oper) + (1|part:oper)"  # model formula

mylF <- lFormula(eval(myformula), data = dt) # Process the formula against the data
Z <- mylF$reTrms$Zt %>% as.matrix() %>% t()  # Extract the Z matrix

b1 <- rnorm(n.part * n.oper, 0 , 4)   # random interecepts for the interaction
b2 <- rnorm(n.oper, 0, 3)             # random interecepts for oper
b3 <- rnorm(n.part, 0, 2)             # random interecepts for part

b <- c(b1, b2, b3)  

dt$Y <- 10 + Z %*% b + rnorm(nrow(dt))
> lmer(eval(myformula), data = dt ) %>% summary()
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Y ~ (1 | part) + (1 | oper) + (1 | part:oper)
   Data: dt

REML criterion at convergence: 3776.8

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.42747 -0.46098  0.01696  0.46941  2.44928 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 part:oper (Intercept) 16.833   4.103   
 oper      (Intercept) 10.183   3.191   
 part      (Intercept)  4.840   2.200   
 Residual               1.009   1.005
```

I have now been running simulations where I hold the st_dev of the random effects for: oper, and part:oper constant and vary the magnitude of the effect of part.  I am seeing some behavior that I do not understand: If I use a equal number of parts and operators, for example 10 and 10, then I can recover the true parameters for standard deviation across a wide range of sd for part.  However, if I change the number of part and operators to, for example 10 and 9, then the results get very wonky and I cannot recover the right params for sd of part or operator.  One misses and one low.  This does not appear to be an affect of just "sample size"...if i increase the number of both parts and operators but make them slightly different from one another I still see this same behavior (example: 20 parts, 19 oper)

See the following images:  this first is a simulated experiment with n=10 parts, n=10 oper.  The red dots are the true population standard deviations for those effects.

[image: 10 op 10 part simulation]

This 2nd is n=10 parts, n=9 oper. Again, the red dots are true pop parameters.

[image: 10 op 9 part simulation]

20 parts, 19 oper:

[image]

Is this to be expected for designs as I described? Or is there likely an error in the code for my simulations?  Perhaps I can't just extract a design matrix so simply as described in the previous post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that the order of the random effects in the `Z` matrix will not always be the same, so you can't always rely on the line `b <- c(b1, b2, b3)` being correct. It appears that `lme4` constructs the model matrix so that it expects the vector of ranom effects `b` to be in descending order, from the one with the most levels to the one with the fewest. In your case, you have the `part:oper` interactions as a grouping variable so this will always have the most levels, so `b1` should come first. When there are equal numbers, such as in the code block above it *appears* that `lme4` might be using alphabetical order, but when you reduce the number for`part` to below that of `oper` then `part` will come next and you will need to use `b <- c(b1, b3, b2)`. So something like this should do the trick:

```
if (n.part < n.oper) {
  b <- c(b1, b3, b2)  
} else {
  b <- c(b1, b2, b3)  
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Robert Long! Saving the day again.